# joda time period.getMonths() is always 0

Tags: java, jodatime

I am trying to calculate the differences between dates, like hours ago, minutes ago , months ago, ...

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "dd/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

Date now = null;
try {
    now = simpleDateFormat.parse(simpleDateFormat.format(new Date()));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Date time = null;
try {
    time = simpleDateFormat.parse(simpleDateFormat.format(timestamp));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Interval interval = new Interval(time.getTime(), now.getTime());
Period period = interval.toPeriod();

Integer s = period.getSeconds();
Integer m = period.getMinutes();
Integer h = period.getHours();
Integer days = period.getDays();

Integer mo = period.getMonths();
Integer y = period.getYears();
```

`Integer mo = period.getMonths();` is always zero

```
i/p=> now =Tue Oct 18 12:15:50 IST 2016
      time=Mon Sep 26 14:38:36 IST 2016

o/p=> s=14
      m=37
      h=21
      days=0
      mo=0
      y=0
```

I also tried `LocalDate` and `DateTime` but had the same issue.

Comment: What is the point of `simpleDateFormat.parse(simpleDateFormat.format(x))`?

Comment: Your dates are less than a month apart, so the fact that you're getting `0` for months is not surprising.  Days, though, should be non-zero.  If you're on Java 8 there's a new built-in date/time library (by the guy who did JodaTime), which includes a new formatter/parser.

Comment: You're getting 0 days because it is 3 weeks. `period.getWeeks()` returns 3. Your could easily have found this out the same way I did, by simply printing the period: `P3WT21H37M14S`

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Java-8 will not help if the OP wants hours, minutes and seconds, too (together with years, months and days).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the way you are doing it now, you get a period that is expressed in weeks. The 'weeks' field of the period will be set, but the years / months / days field will not be set.

If you want a period with years, months, days and time, then you need to specify the period type when you call `toPeriod` on the interval:

```
Period period = interval.toPeriod(PeriodType.yearMonthDayTime());
```

Result:

```
i/p=> now =Tue Oct 18 12:15:50 IST 2016
      time=Mon Sep 26 14:38:36 IST 2016

o/p=> s=14
      m=37
      h=21
      days=21
      mo=0
      y=0
```

Ofcourse the months and years field are still 0 with this example because the two dates are less than a month apart.